# Filter mlflow runs by run name (runName)

Tags: azure, databricks, mlflow

How to filter out runs whose runName starts with the string "iteration11_run_number"?

Answer (score 1):

runName parameter can be accessed by `tags."mlflow.runName"`. `mlflow.runName` is inside quotes because it has a special character in it, the `.`. Otherwise you can go on without putting tag name in parentheses.

To filter, use this query:
`tags."mlflow.runName" LIKE "iteration11_run_number%"`

As the mlflow query is like SQL `WHERE` query, you can use `LIKE` keyword. In SQL the `%` wildcard is used to denote 0, 1, or more characters, and `_` wildcard is used to denote 1 character.

For more details, refer to the [documentation](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/search-syntax.html#).

Answer (score 1):

`run_name LIKE "pattern"` works for me too.

See the screenshot below for an example how to use it in the web interface

[image]